# R alignment of axis labels with expressions

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot a variable name and its symbol. Because some variables have long names, I'm attempting to mix line breaks with the axis labels. This causes funny things to happen in the alignments:

```
par(mar=c(1,12,1,1))

plot( y=1:6, 1:6, yaxt="n", ylim=c(1,6), ylab="" )

axis(2, at=6:1, las=1,
     labels=c(
  expression( paste( 'Variable, ',rho, sep="" ) ),
  expression( paste( 'Another variable,\n',alpha, sep="" ) ),
  expression( paste( 'Also\nvariable,\n',beta, sep="" ) ),
  expression( paste( 'This\nvariable too, ',Gamma, sep="" ) ),
  expression( paste( 'Verybigname\nvariable,',C[zeta], sep="" ) ),
  expression( paste( 'Verybigname\nvariable,',C[zeta],"moretext\n",C[delta], sep="" ) ) ))
```

The first line (from the top) is what I expected the others to look like in some way, which is justified next to the axis.

The rest of the lines all show the basic problem that the variable name is justified with respect to the second element of the expression, not to the axis. This gets particularly weird in the last line where a large space is inserted between the variable name and its symbol.

Ideally, I would like the labels right justified, and centered on the tick mark.

Comment: I think you should pad the alignments "by hand". Or switch over to `text` with xpd=TRUE.

Comment: Do you want labels in one line?

Comment: @Geo-sp no, that's why I added line breaks in the variable names

Comment: have you tried `padj` argument?

Answer (score 5):

This is the best I can do with using `text` with positioning on the side "by hand". (Many efforts with axis using 'hadj' and 'padj' failed.) To try to get the plotmath greeks under the text values, I needed to use the `atop` function. This in turn required using `phantom`. I mostly use pure plotmath with `~` and `*` as connectors rather than relying on `paste`, but here your use of "\n" does acomplish a line break (which I found surprising). By the way, the plotmath `paste` function does not actually accept a `sep` argument.

```
par(mar=c(1,12,1,1))
plot( y=1:6, 1:6, yaxt="n", ylim=c(1,6), ylab="" )

axis(2, at=6:1, las=1,
     labels=rep("",6 ))
text( 0.5, 6:1- c(0,0,.2,.1,.1,.1), c(
   expression( Variable~~rho ) ,
   expression( atop(~~Another~variable, phantom("Another~variable")~alpha)  ),
   expression( atop(paste( '        Also\n   variable') ,phantom("variable")~beta ) ),
   expression( atop( paste( '            This\nvariable too') ,phantom("           ")~Gamma ) ),
   expression( atop( paste( '   Verybigname\n            variable,'),phantom("  Verybigname")~C[zeta] ) ),
   expression(  paste( '   Verybigname\nvariable,',C[zeta],"moretext\n",C[delta] ) ) ), 
xpd=TRUE ,adj=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I too was surprised that \n worked. And this explains why sep="" wasn't doing anything!

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `ggplot2`, using `atop` for multi-line.
It will automatically position the labels as you want

```
library(ggplot2)
DF <- data.frame(x = 1:6, y = 1:6)
labels = c(
  expression( Variable~~rho ) ,
  expression( atop(~~Another~variable, phantom("Another~variable")~alpha)  ),
  expression( atop(paste( '        Also\n   variable') ,phantom("variable")~beta ) ),
  expression( atop( paste( '            This\nvariable too') ,phantom("           ")~Gamma ) ),
  expression( atop( paste( '   Verybigname\n            variable,'),phantom("  Verybigname")~C[zeta] ) ),
  expression(  paste( '   Verybigname\nvariable,',C[zeta],"moretext\n",C[delta] ) ) )

ggplot(DF, aes(x = x, y, y = y)) +
geom_point() +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:6, labels = rev(labels))
```

[image: ggplot and plotmath labels]

I think it is possible to make a fonction that wrap mixed text-plotmath labels, but it seems more complicated that manually create your labels.