# preventing centering multilayered caption in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

This is part-2 to my previous question ([getting constant text size while using atop function in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235655/getting-constant-text-size-while-using-atop-function-in-r/53237475?noredirect=1#comment93364738_53237475)).

Now the issue relates to how I can prevent `plotmath` from centering the text to avoid the extra spacing (highlighted here in yellow). I want everything aligned to the right side of the plot.

(Unfortunately, I can't replace `substitute` with `expression` if that's what your suggestion is going to be.)

Any suggestions?

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot()  +
  labs(caption = substitute(atop(
    atop(
      displaystyle("layer1 is small"),
      displaystyle("layer2 is a bit longer")
    ),
    "layer3 is super-duper longgggggggg"
  )))
```

[image]

Comment: There are already few related question (see plotmath alignment). E.g., would manually adding spaces as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781950/r-alignment-of-axis-labels-with-expressions would be acceptable? Rather than actually manually trying different numbers of spaces it could be somewhat automatized.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that all of them use `expression` to create the caption, while I am using `substitute`. The solutions provided of course don't work well with `substitute`. (In case you are wondering why the obsession with `substitute`, this is the kind of context where I am using it- https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/blob/c07736cc4abfc81430b3e725e57a60b883a444d9/R/helpers_ggbetween_subtitles.R#L167-L231)

Comment: So I guess the problem is that the text is not of fixed length. Why don't you update your example a little where manually adding, say, 30 spaces doesn't fix the problem? Then I'll give it a try.

Comment: The text in `layer 2` and `layer 3` are of fixed length, so that will be easy to fix. It's the `layer 1` that will vary because the user can choose to enter `caption` of any length they want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with good news. Here's a function that adds enough leading spaces to `from` as to be as long as the longest element from the list `to`:

```
push <- function(from, to)
  sprintf(paste("%", max(nchar(from), max(nchar(to))), "s"), from)
```

Next we have three layers, which also may use `substitute` (as I understand, in your case only the first one uses it).

```
l1 <- substitute("layer1 is small")
l2 <- "layer2 is a bit longer"
l3 <- "layer3 is super-duper longgggggggg"
```

Now the bad news is that `push` achieves the desired effect only with mono fonts, which is not the default family in `ggplot2`. There are multiple question on SO regarding fonts, so perhaps you may import some other mono font, if you prefer.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot()  +
  labs(caption = substitute(atop(atop(textstyle(l1), textstyle(l2)), textstyle(l3)), 
                            list(l1 = push(l1, list(l2 ,l3)),
                                 l2 = push(l2, list(l1, l3)), 
                                 l3 = push(l3, list(l2, l3))))) +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(family = "mono"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

easiest might be to add text grobs row by row in a gtable,

```
gtable_add_caption <- function(p, cap, g = ggplotGrob(p), 
                               hjust=1, x=unit(1,"npc"), pad = unit(c(2,2),"mm"),
                               ...){

  for(ii in seq_along(cap)){
    line <- tryCatch(parse(text = cap[ii]), error = function(e) cap[ii])
    tg <- textGrob(line, x = x - pad[1], hjust = hjust, gp=gpar(...))
    hg <- grobHeight(tg) 
    g <- gtable_add_rows(g, hg + pad[2])
    g <- gtable_add_grob(g, tg, t = nrow(g), l=1, r=ncol(g))
  }

  g
}

p <- ggplot()
ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() ->p
g <- gtable_add_caption(p, c("first line", "integral(frac(1,x-1)*dx,alpha,beta)", "thirdddddddddddddddddd line"))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```